# SQL Trigger - Having one is messing up new SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am able to manually execute the following code:

```
UPDATE pfields_cont p, members m
   SET m.member_group_id = 6
 WHERE p.member_id = m.member_id
   AND m.member_group_id != 6
   AND p.field_2 = 'Teacher';
```

However, if I try creating a Trigger with the same code as above, I get this error when creating a new user in my database:

> Can't update table 'members' in stored function/trigger because it is
> already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
> (1442)

Can anybody help fix the trigger?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Full trigger definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `newTeacher` AFTER INSERT ON `members` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE
    pfields_cont p,
    members m
SET
    m.member_group_id = 6
WHERE
    p.member_id = m.member_id
    AND m.member_group_id != 6
    AND p.field_2 = 'Teacher'
```

Comment: How are you "...creating a new user in my database..."? It seems your creation query is interfering with the trigger.

Comment: What is event is the trigger listening to?

Comment: @TheImpaler it is an INSERT command. Something like: "INSERT INTO `members` ( `group_id`, `group_others`, `joined`, `ip`, `timezone` ... ) VALUES ( 1, '' ... )".

Comment: The error means that you cannot refer to the **same** table anywhere within the trigger's handling. (for reading or writing)

Comment: @PaulT. So I shouldn't be mentioning the table "members" within the trigger? How would I make it work then?

Comment: Since the full trigger definition is not present, which table has the trigger: `members` or `pfields_cont`?

Comment: @PaulT. right now it's ``members``. I'll edit the post and add the entire trigger definition.

Comment: So it looks like all you're basically trying to do, is update `field_2` to teacher where the `member_group_id` != 6?  However, I'm a little confused about this part of the full definition that's not in the first SQL: `AND m.member_group_id != 6`? Likely ok as probably trying to avoid setting to 6 if already 6?

Comment: @PaulT. yes, you're right. The ``AND m.member_group_id != 6`` is just another check I added to the trigger. I'll edit the main post again, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237771/discussion-between-paul-t-and-hilas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot refer to the same table in a trigger's definition (for reading or writing), the trigger handling can be simplified based on setting the `member_group_id` to 6 if `field_2` is `Teacher`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `newTeacher` BEFORE INSERT ON `members`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE
BEGIN
    Declare fieldInfo varchar(30);

    SELECT field_2 INTO fieldInfo 
      FROM pfields_cont 
     WHERE pfields_cont.member_id = NEW.member_ID;

    IF fieldInfo = 'Teacher' THEN
        SET NEW.member_group_id = 6;
    END IF;
END;
```